# command to run existing imahe of RabbitMQ on a pod

Tags: kubernetes

Can anyone please help me to find which command is used to run an existing image of rabbitMQ on a pod and check if it is done?

Comment: Pleases describe your issue with more details.

Answer (score 0):

> which command is used to run an existing image of rabbitMQ

You can check by getting the YAML output from the cluster or from the YAML config file

to get the YAML output of RabbitMQ POD you can do

```
kubectl get <deployment/statefulet/pod> rabbitmq <name of resource> -o yaml
```

example

```
kubectl get deployment rabbitmq
```

in YAML you can check the Command or ARG getting passed to image which is running the image.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: rabbitmq
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq
        image: rabbitmq:3-management
        command: ["test"]
        env:
        - name: "RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE"
          value: "1WqgH8N2v1qDBDZDbNy8Bg9IkPWLEpu79m6q+0t36lQ="
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq
          name: rabbitmq-data
      volumes:
        - name: rabbitmq-data
          hostPath:
            path: /data/rabbitmq
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

If you want to check the running command inside the docker file

Here is the docker file : [Click here](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/master/Dockerfile-alpine.template)